# logistic map averaged values graphed

Tags: fractals, chaos-theory

For the logistic map: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map

For a given x, taking the average of n values on the logistic map,
gives a converging value.

ie for the x domain 3.56 <= x < 4, with n=100000 averaged values for each x, with a x step size of 0.00001 the graph is:

[image: logistic map 100000 averaged values, 0.00001 step size, x between 3.56 and 4 domain]

The Mathematica code:

```
(*code is slow*) 
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] := 4 a*x (1 - x);

xAverages = {};
For[i = 0.89, i < 1, i = i + 0.00001,
 a = i;
 b = Mean[NestList[f, 0.5, 100000]];
 AppendTo[xAverages, b];
 ]

xAverages;
ListPlot[xAverages]
```

I'm curious about the properties of this graph, ie some x values will converge faster, like the flat sections, which are not chaotic.  Also the steep slope sections that form the edges of the flat sections are a transition from the chaotic regions to the non chaotic regions.  Can this averaged graph be used to derive the Feigenbaum constant in a similar way to the logistic map as well?

Here is the graph of the logistic map over the same x domain 3.56 <= x < 4 :

[image: logistic map x 3.56 to 4]

```
ListPlot[Flatten[Table[x = Table[0, {1000}];
   x[[1]] = .01;
   Do[x[[i + 1]] = r*x[[i]] (1 - x[[i]]), {i, 999}];
   {r, #} & /@ x[[-100 ;;]], {r, L1}], 1]]


Flatten[Table[x = Table[0, {1000}];
  x[[1]] = .01;
  Do[x[[i + 1]] = r*x[[i]] (1 - x[[i]]), {i, 999}];
  {r, #} & /@ x[[-100 ;;]], {r, L1}], 1]
```

Comment: The non-chaotic regions correspond to hyperbolic components in the Mandelbrot set, via a transformation of $f_r(x) = rx(1-x)$ to $f_c(z) = z^2+c$.  You can use successive $\operatorname{argmin} |z_n|$ to guess the period of the component $p$, then solve $f_c^p(z) = z$ to get a point in the limit cycle (e.g. using Newton's method). The point is interior if the derivative w.r.t. $z$ of the limit cycle has magnitude less than $1$. Then the limit of the average is the average of the limit cycle.  This may accelerate computations, especially if you exploit continuity properties.

Comment: Does any of that apply (or do you have any other info) for the average values on the chaotic regions?  Thanks.